# Premium News script

Tags: google-news

what are possible premium News script available?
We are a small company that wants to shift our attention to News/Blogging service. What's the best premium script that we can buy for this?

Answer (score 1):

what scripts are you talking about. for what platform... asp...php..coldfusion...

Are you a developer? Than it's really easy to write your own site/cms in php/java/ruby etc.
If you are experienced php programmer  - just pick up a copy of some framework like CI or Cake PHP and roll own your own site. large news companies usually develop their own CMS (content managament system) for blogging/news management.

For less experienced programmers IMHo - I would just download Wordpress CMS and some custom theme. There are some big sites that use Wordpress (well... relatively big...like phandroid.com).

IMHO - I would not buy any "news scripts". there are plethora of free open source script and script examples all over the internet.

just google it.

Comment: Yea, a news site really isn't that much different from a standard blog site in terms of the content to be managed. And many news sites do use Wordpress as their CMS. Many other general-purpose CMSes also allow you to post dated articles and can be easily adaptable for a news site.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Wordpress as a news site, there are plugins for NewsML from feedsyndicate.com that will allow you to import/export articles.